# Increasing HTTP client timeout

Tags: java, android, http, tomcat

I'll get right into the subject

I have a server that works a music recommendation system ( for some kind of application)
the server has a very large database

So i made a singleton constructor of the recommendation system.
My problem is 
the first time this constructor is being created it has to run a training data and it connects to the database a lot which is a time consuming operation

This has to run only the first time according to my singleton object and then afterwards, it'll be able to use the results of the constructor right away

My problem is that on the first HTTP request from my PC to the server, the explorer times out and the singleton object is never created on the server

I think my solution would be in extending the wait time of the explorer until the server finishes computation and returns with result, however 
if someone has a better solution i'd be greatly in his dept

I really need an easy applicable solution that requires minimal effort because the delivery deadline is closing up and i need to wrap the project as fast as possible

Thanks again

Comment: Is it possible for your server to return some data to the browser and still keep on working in the background?

Comment: Not really no, because it goes into the training process , and it has to be all done before giving an HTTP response

Answer (score 2):

Few comments/suggestions

- Increasing timeout is one way but its not sure shot way of solving the problem. The time taken by the recommendation system may not always be same over the time.
- I suggest another approach to solve this. Not sure if its an option for you, but Will it be possible to create the recommendation system **asynchronously** in a separate thread so that the server start up is not held back by this ?
- If you could do above, then provision a **flag** which indicates that recommendation system has started.
- Meanwhile if you receive any request, first check the flag if the flag indicate that the recommendation system has not yet started, the return some meaningful message/status.
- This way you will get the response immediately and based on the response you can work out retries on the client side.

Please note that this will be substantial change on the server side. Just an opinion to improve the things further and full proof way of avoiding timeout.

Comment: I am in almost total agreeing state with your answer, i'll give it a try and let you know about the results

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the connection time out using below

```
HttpResponse response = null;
final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
// 60 second connection timeout
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 60000);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

Comment: Where do i add this into the client side?
My problem is that the browser times out before the server is free to respond

Comment: yes, you need to add this where you are making a HTTP call with the server.